# Batch saving webpages

Tags: html, download-manager

I need to save multiple pages to my harddisk.The pages have a pattern like this:

```
http://example.com/page1.html
http://example.com/page2.html
http://example.com/page3.html
.
.
.
.
```

I need to save a large number of webpages(about 5000).I tried using IDM but it hangs when I enter the links maybe due to the large number of pages.I also tried WinHTTrack but it saves the pages along with the unneccessary things such as pdf's from the site which i really don't need.

Can you recommend a software?thanks

Comment: What about [Save entire website to your hard disk](http://www.exisoftware.com/news/save-website.html) ??

Comment: and [Web2Disk](http://www.inspyder.com/products/Web2Disk/Default.aspx)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website

Comment: @WingedPanther but there are a lot of files(such as PDF's and images) on the website which i really don't need and saving the whole website would just be a waste of time and bandwidth.

Comment: My copy of WinHTTtrack lets me exclude file types. Did you investigate the project options?

Comment: Under what operating system? When you say the pages have a pattern, do you mean that you have a list of all the URLs, or do you need to build a list of URLs (e.g. with a series of numbers)? Do you just want the HTML files or also the embedded images etc.?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/):

- free and open source
- Linux, [Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), Mac (`brew install wget`)
- CLI
- tons of features such as the ability not to download PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into the combination of [python](http://python.org) and [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) this will enable you to construct a `spider` that will walk the web site(s) following the rules that you set on what content to download and save.

Points to consider:

- Free & Open Source
- Cross platform will run on Windows/Linux/Mac
- Only download the content that you specify so saves bandwidth/time/space
- Large StackOverflow & on-line communities

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, you can use **[DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)** which is a very robust mass downloading tool.

Just add a new download job and make sure to add in the appropriate batch descriptor:
[image]

Then all of the downloads will be added and automatically start. If a page is a 404, then dTa will just ignore without writing that page to the disk. It's that simple!